# Create Binary Indicator variable for column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below.  I would like to create a column for every value in the categories column, (example: Sandwhiches, Restaurants...)  The column would have a 0 or 1 indicating whether the record had the value.  Is this something I could do with getdummies or is there another way someone could suggest?

Code:

```
print df1[1:3]
```

Sample Data:

```
                    address  \
4             4719 N 20Th St   
14  9616 E Independence Blvd   

                                           attributes             business_id  \
4   {u'GoodForMeal': {u'dessert': False, u'latenig...  duHFBe87uNSXImQmvBh87Q   
14  {u'Alcohol': u'full_bar', u'HasTV': True, u'No...  SDMRxmcKPNt1AHPBKqO64Q   

                                           categories      city  \
4                           [Sandwiches, Restaurants]   Phoenix   
14  [Burgers, Bars, Restaurants, Sports Bars, Nigh...  Matthews   

                                                hours  is_open   latitude  \
4                                                  {}        0  33.505928   
14  {u'Monday': u'11:00-0:00', u'Tuesday': u'11:00...        1  35.135196   

     longitude        name neighborhood postal_code  review_count  stars state  
4  -112.038847     Blimpie                    85016            10    4.5    AZ  
14  -80.714683  Applebee's                    28105            21    2.0    NC
```

Update:

```
testdummies = pd.concat(df1["categories"],pd.get_dummies(df1["categories"]))
testdummies.head()

Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1dae1382c2ba> in <module>()
      1 # 13) create dummy variables for Categories
      2 
----> 3 testdummies = pd.concat(df1["categories"],pd.get_dummies(df1["categories"]))
      4 testdummies.head()

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in get_dummies(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na, columns, sparse, drop_first)
   1102     else:
   1103         result = _get_dummies_1d(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na,
-> 1104                                  sparse=sparse, drop_first=drop_first)
   1105     return result
   1106 

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.pyc in _get_dummies_1d(data, prefix, prefix_sep, dummy_na, sparse, drop_first)
   1109                     sparse=False, drop_first=False):
   1110     # Series avoids inconsistent NaN handling
-> 1111     codes, levels = _factorize_from_iterable(Series(data))
   1112 
   1113     def get_empty_Frame(data, sparse):

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.pyc in _factorize_from_iterable(values)
   2038         codes = values.codes
   2039     else:
-> 2040         cat = Categorical(values, ordered=True)
   2041         categories = cat.categories
   2042         codes = cat.codes

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/categorical.pyc in __init__(self, values, categories, ordered, name, fastpath)
    288                 codes, categories = factorize(values, sort=True)
    289             except TypeError:
--> 290                 codes, categories = factorize(values, sort=False)
    291                 if ordered:
    292                     # raise, as we don't have a sortable data structure and so

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.pyc in factorize(values, sort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    311     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(vals))
    312     uniques = vec_klass()
--> 313     labels = table.get_labels(vals, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, True)
    314 
    315     labels = _ensure_platform_int(labels)

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas/hashtable.c:15447)()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Update:

Code:

```
bus_rev_cat = pd.get_dummies(bus_rev['categories'].apply(pd.Series))
bus_rev2 = pd.concat([bus_rev,bus_rev_cat],axis=1)
print(bus_rev2[1:10])

Sample Data:

                  user_id             business_id  stars_x  \
1  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  XSiqtcVEsP6dLOL7ZA9OxA        4   
2  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  v95ot_TNwTk1iJ5n56dR0g        3   
3  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  uloYxyRAMesZzI99mfNInA        2   
4  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  gtcsOodbmk4E0TulYHnlHA        4   
5  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  lOd50CiDJeNWmN_KsvR2rg        3   
6  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  7hUp4XxmUCGqvPFAM8IJww        3   
7  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  Ze4VPogvcD7inc3QuvY_yg        2   
8  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  txAKid34IUd9spo6MLF_Sw        3   
9  CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw  oiknQaNH9cGC6UBWC8S_Zg        3   

                  address                                         attributes  \
1        522 Yonge Street  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
2     1661 Denison Street  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
3    4101 Rutherford Road  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
4      815 W Bloor Street  {u'Alcohol': u'full_bar', u'HasTV': False, u'N...   
5         114 Laird Drive  {u'GoodForMeal': {u'dessert': False, u'latenig...   
6     300 Borough Dr, 215  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
7  5117 Sheppard Avenue E  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
8             205 Main St  {u'BusinessParking': {u'garage': False, u'stre...   
9       6347 Yonge Street  {u'GoodForMeal': {u'dessert': False, u'latenig...   

                                          categories         city  \
1                     [Restaurants, Ramen, Japanese]      Toronto   
2                    [Chinese, Seafood, Restaurants]      Markham   
3                             [Italian, Restaurants]   Woodbridge   
4  [Food, Coffee & Tea, Sandwiches, Cafes, Cockta...      Toronto   
5                [Japanese, Sushi Bars, Restaurants]    East York   
6  [Restaurants, Canadian (New), Steakhouses, Ame...  Scarborough   
7  [Canadian (New), Restaurants, Breakfast & Brunch]      Toronto   
8             [Italian, Restaurants, Canadian (New)]      Markham   
9                              [Restaurants, Korean]      Toronto   

                                               hours  is_open   latitude  \
1  {u'Monday': u'11:00-22:00', u'Tuesday': u'11:0...        1  43.663689   
2                                                 {}        0  43.834295   
3  {u'Monday': u'12:00-22:00', u'Tuesday': u'12:0...        1  43.823486   
4  {u'Monday': u'12:00-2:00', u'Tuesday': u'12:00...        1  43.662726   
5  {u'Tuesday': u'17:00-22:00', u'Friday': u'17:0...        0  43.706665   
6  {u'Monday': u'11:00-0:00', u'Tuesday': u'11:00...        1  43.776146   
7  {u'Monday': u'0:00-0:00', u'Tuesday': u'0:00-0...        1  43.793599   
8                                                 {}        1  43.868463   
9                                                 {}        0  43.796237   

         ...         6_Pizza 6_Restaurants 7_Bars 7_Canadian (New)  7_French  \
1        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
2        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
3        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
4        ...               0             0      1                0         0   
5        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
6        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
7        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
8        ...               0             0      0                0         0   
9        ...               0             0      0                0         0   

   7_Restaurants 8_Mediterranean 8_Nightlife  8_Southern  8_Specialty Food  
1              0               0           0           0                 0  
2              0               0           0           0                 0  
3              0               0           0           0                 0  
4              0               0           1           0                 0  
5              0               0           0           0                 0  
6              0               0           0           0                 0  
7              0               0           0           0                 0  
8              0               0           0           0                 0  
9              0               0           0           0                 0  

[9 rows x 149 columns]
```

Comment: Have you checked `get_dummies`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) which does exactly what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Categorical": ["a", "b", "c", "a"]})
df

>>>     Categorical
    0   a
    1   b
    2   c
    3   a


pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df["Categorical"])], axis=1)

>>>     Categorical     a   b   c
    0   a               1   0   0
    1   b               0   1   0
    2   c               0   0   1
    3   a               1   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I tried get_dummies.  I updated the original post with the code I tried and the error I got.  Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @modLmakur You need to put your objects you want to concatenate into a list in order to make it work. I updated my example accordingly using `concat`.

Comment: @pansen  I added an update above with sample data from the code I ran creating dummy variables.  I'm wondering why there are numbers added to the beginning of the dummy variable names.  It seems like sometimes there's multiple versions of the dummy variable like 6_bar, 15_bar, does this have to do with the original form of the "categories" column?  Can you suggest how I could fix it so there aren't multiple versions of the dummy variable?  Thanks.